# PHP: Set php variable on javascript onclick

Tags: php

How do I set a php variable when a radio button is clicked?

Or is there any other way without using ajax.

What I would like to do is set

```
$_SESSION['a'] = $a;
```

Where $a is an array of answers which was initially set to 0.

I have a radio button of questions with 4 options. When a user clicks on a radio button, I would like my session to record that radio button.

I was thinking of OnClick function on the radio button.

How do I do this. or how do I store that chosen radio button in the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by only JavaScript its not possible you need to use ajax to do this or by submitting form

Comment: Ok, that being said. I am in my way of form submit. How do I save it in a session on form submit. Do I set it in session after submit and onload of the next page?

Comment: @Sid yes you can do by this way

Comment: Well at first I did not understand Form Submit. when I did trial and error, my results was perfect for what I wished. Thanks for this sir.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the answers in single form submit and then process the answers on PHP side.

```
<p>
<input name="question1" type="radio" value="a" />
<input name="question1" type="radio" value="b" />
<input name="question1" type="radio" value="c" />
<input name="question1" type="radio" value="d" />
</p>
```

On PHP side

```
$_SESSION['a'] = $_POST['question1']; // it will be either a, b, c, d
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only point is to save it for user enhancement (i.e. it has no meaning on the server-side, you just want the browser to remember it for user comfort), it may be better to save the data on the client-side only, on localStorage (preferable) or on Cookies.

The complete, server-side processing would happen when you submit the form.